# I want to show the time in GMT from (1800+0100)

Tags: c#, gmt

I have a field in a table with varchar data type which contains the time as 1800+0100, how can I show it like this 19:00 GMT? Is there any C# method which takes the time as 1800+0100 and converts to 19:00?

Thanks in advance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1800+0100 is actually 17:00 GMT, *not* 19:00.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your time is actually in [ISO-8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) then you can do this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("1800+0100", "HHmmzzz", null,
                                  DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
Console.WriteLine(dt.TimeOfDay);  // 17:00:00
```

But notice that this (correctly) outputs *"17:00:00"*, not *"19:00:00"*.

If your string isn't in ISO-8601 format -- and *"1800+0100"* really is meant to represent 19:00 GMT -- then you'll need to parse the string manually, or maybe pre-process it before passing it to `ParseExact`. Possibly something like this:

```
string s = "1800+0100";

string temp = s.Substring(0, 4) + ((s[4] == '+') ? '-' : '+') + s.Substring(5);
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(temp, "HHmmzzz", null,
                                  DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
Console.WriteLine(dt.TimeOfDay);  // 19:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you Luke, you explained with example, awesome! it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime` class supports [`Add` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods.aspx) for `DateTime` objects. You can convert one time to another by adding any unit of time you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) for this. You begin by [constructing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351980.aspx) an instance from a time and an offset, and then just fetch the [UtcDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.utcdatetime.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

Beware though that UK only uses GMT (UniversalTime) in winter and summer time in summer.